# Plotting graph with dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot my table into a graph which has dates, from what I've learnt I've changed the date column into recognisable date by

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y%m%d")
```

My data looks something like this:

|  | Date | DailyPositive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 1 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 |
| 3 | 20200103 | 4 |

When I try plotting it, my graphs came out like this, I'm assuming it somehow plotted against the index instead?

[image]

How do I plot the date at X axis, and the cases at Y-axis?
Also since my date runs across two years, is there a way for to make the X-axis date go in like maybe few months apart?

I've searched around and saw way too many different solutions for me to understand :(

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For a regular plot, you just can use `line`

```
DF2.plot.line(x="Date", y="DailyPositive")
```

[image]

For adding some space, you can set the `xlim` kind of dynamically like this:

```
DF2.plot.line(x="Date", y="DailyPositive", xlim=[min(DF2["Date"]) + pd.DateOffset(-1), max(DF2["Date"]) + pd.DateOffset(1)])
```

[image]